# Responsive filemanager upload error

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, centos, responsive-filemanager

I have a problem in my reponsive filemanager plugin. I am using [this plugin](http://responsivefilemanager.com/). On my localhost version it running smoothly but after I upload on my Centos server I can't upload the documents running on MS Applications like (excel and ms word). It turns it into a zip folder.

My system runs on Codeigniter 3 HMVC and I also set the permissions of responsive filemanager (source and thumbs) permission to 777.

Images are working fine and txt. I also try to addType the ms application on my httpd.conf file and restart my server and it still same error.

Can you help me with my problem? I really want to use this plugin because it has a nice UI and settings. I don't know if it is a server problem.

Comment: What does "it turns into a zip folder" mean? Modern Microsoft Office documents like `.docx` and `.xlsx` files really _are_ zip files that contain data files.

Comment: How can I preview it using docx or xlsx?

Comment: Again, what do you mean when you say "it turns into a zip folder"?

Comment: In my process I am uploading an excel file then after success and preview it in my filemanager it becomes a zip folder and when I try to download the file and extract it. It contains a folder like this `_rels, docProps, xl` and an xml file `[Content_Types]`.

Comment: When you preview it in _what_ file manager? Do you download the file again? Or do you mean a file manager on your CentOS server?

Comment: I am using a pugin `Responsive Filemanager` on my website. And to that plugin is where I upload my files.

Comment: I have the same problem, when I upload a pptx file (ex. test.pptx) Responsive filemanager changes the file name to pptx (test.zip) so when I download the file I cant open it. Anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I know its kinda late but this is how I solved this issue.

go into 'pathToFilemanager/include/mime_type_lib.php' 
and comment or remove "application/zip" => "zip" from your $mime_types array.